# How to move files using Regex or String Formatting in Python

Tags: python, regex, tensorflow, image-processing, directory

I am a beginner in the field of Data Science and I am working with Data Preprocessing in python. However, I am working with the Fingers Dataset so I want to move the pictures so every pic fits in its own directory to be able to use **ImageDataGenerator** and **flowfromdirectory** to import the pictures and apply rescaling, flipping... etc

the code below shows what I'm trying to do...

```
dataset_path = "/tmp/extracted_fingers/fingers"
train_set = os.path.join(dataset_path, "train/")
test_set = os.path.join(dataset_path, "test/")

for i in range(6):
    os.mkdir("/tmp/extracted_fingers/fingers/train/" + str(i) + "L")
    os.mkdir("/tmp/extracted_fingers/fingers/test/" + str(i) + "L")
for i in range(6):
    os.mkdir("/tmp/extracted_fingers/fingers/train/" + str(i) + "R")
    os.mkdir("/tmp/extracted_fingers/fingers/test/" + str(i) + "R")

L_0_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*0L.png")
L_1_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*1L.png")
L_2_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*2L.png")
L_3_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*3L.png")
L_4_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*4L.png")
L_5_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*5L.png")
R_0_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*0R.png")
R_1_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*1R.png")
R_2_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*2R.png")
R_3_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*3R.png")
R_4_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*4R.png")
R_5_tr = glob.glob(train_set + "*5R.png")

L_0_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*0L.png")
L_1_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*1L.png")
L_2_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*2L.png")
L_3_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*3L.png")
L_4_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*4L.png")
L_5_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*5L.png")
R_0_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*0R.png")
R_1_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*1R.png")
R_2_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*2R.png")
R_3_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*3R.png")
R_4_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*4R.png")
R_5_ts = glob.glob(test_set + "*5R.png")

shutil.move(L_0_tr, "0L")
shutil.move(L_1_tr, "1L")
shutil.move(L_2_tr, "2L")
shutil.move(L_3_tr, "3L")
shutil.move(L_4_tr, "4L")
shutil.move(L_5_tr, "5L")
shutil.move(R_0_tr, "0R")
shutil.move(R_1_tr, "1R")
shutil.move(R_2_tr, "2R")
shutil.move(R_3_tr, "3R")
shutil.move(R_4_tr, "4R")
shutil.move(R_5_tr, "5R")

shutil.move(L_0_ts, "0L")
shutil.move(L_1_ts, "1L")
shutil.move(L_2_ts, "2L")
shutil.move(L_3_ts, "3L")
shutil.move(L_4_ts, "4L")
shutil.move(L_5_ts, "5L")
shutil.move(R_0_ts, "0R")
shutil.move(R_1_ts, "1R")
shutil.move(R_2_ts, "2R")
shutil.move(R_3_ts, "3R")
shutil.move(R_4_ts, "4R")
shutil.move(R_5_ts, "5R")
```

Now this way can do the job, but I am 100% sure there are better ways with much less typing to do it, so I, as a beginner, am trying to do it...

I do not know whether it can be done by loops, Regex, and string formatting or any other way...

However, if anyone could help me, I will be appreciated...

A little help can be good.

Thanks in advance.
Much Love

**Note:** if you want I can give more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own way of doing it, however, I will share the code in case of someone need it...

```
def moving_pics(files_set):
    for i in range(0, 6):
        direction = glob.glob(files_set + "*" + str(i) + "L.png")
        for p in direction:
            shutil.move(p, files_set + str(i) + "L")

    for i in range(0, 6):
        sec_direction = glob.glob(files_set + "*" + str(i) + "R.png")
        for p2 in sec_direction:
            shutil.move(p2, files_set + str(i) + "R")
```

then you pass the path to the function parameter

**Note: **you need to pass the path as it ends with "/".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it'll help much, but you can use the **map** built-in function to reduce a few lines.

```
map(lambda x: shutil.move(glob.glob(train_set + "*"+str(x)+"R.png"),str(x)+"R"), range(0,6))
map(lambda x: shutil.move(glob.glob(train_set + "*"+str(x)+"L.png"),str(x)+"L"), range(0,6))

map(lambda x: shutil.move(glob.glob(test_set + "*"+str(x)+"R.png"),str(x)+"R"), range(0,6))
map(lambda x: shutil.move(glob.glob(test_set + "*"+str(x)+"L.png"),str(x)+"L"), range(0,6))
```

Comment: Thank you, but I found my own way However THANK YOU for trying to help.